# infinite series,comparision test,convergence divergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3V6ZC.png)
here as in example 3 the answer of the book is convergence but as (in round shape in photo ) i had solved and my answer is coming divergence by comparision test so what `s wrong in my answer (as divergence) so please can you clarify by doubt or misconcept here if any

Comment: For one, your $u_n$ does NOT go to infinity.

Comment: And, even if it did, how would this in tandem with the Comparison Test prove divergence?  My gut tells me you are misunderstanding the Comparison Test.

Comment: un=ln n/n now integration of (ln / n)dn  limits 1 to infinity taking y=ln n so dy =1/n dn so now integration is ydy limits 0 to infinity which is y^2 / 2 limits 0 to infinity is so it will be infinity hence by integral test it diverges

Comment: also vn = 1/sqrt(n) so by p test it is divergence so the whole series diverges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have taken wrong Vn
if $$Vn = n^{(\frac{-3}{2})}$$
than by p test it converge